# How to enrich request body of the apis globally

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have 50 apis deployed on a tomcat container with nginx in front of it. All of them written in java (spring)
Every api has its own request payload. Now I am asked to enrich every request
payload with additional parameters. The parameters remain same for all payloads.

For instance if api A expects :

```
{
    "name":"somename",
    "surname":"somesurname"
}
```

it should be changed to

```
{
    "requester_id":"",
    "reason": "",
    "name":"somename",
    "surname":"somesurname"
}
```

if api B expects :

```
{
    "platenumber":"someplatenumber",
}
```

it should be changed to

```
{
    "requester_id":"",
    "reason": "",
    "platenumber":"someplatenumber",
}
```

One of the solution is to amend every request body of each api (50!) which takes some time.
Hence my question is there any way to add additional parameters globally to request body of all apis?

Comment: Not possible as far as I'm aware but might be possible to add those as headers

Comment: Any particular reasons that you have added a tag for Spring Integration: https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration ?

Comment: It occurred to me that it is possible to create some gateway, where one can intercept incoming requests, enrich them with required parameters then forward it to corresponding api by using spring integration.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into @ControllerAdvice

http://www.javabyexamples.com/quick-guide-to-responsebodyadvice-in-spring-mvc

```
import org.springframework.core.MethodParameter;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.server.ServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.http.server.ServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyAdvice;

@ControllerAdvice
public class MyAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice<Object> {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object body, 
                                  MethodParameter returnType, 
                                  MediaType selectedContentType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType, 
                                  ServerHttpRequest request, 
                                  ServerHttpResponse response) {
        // MODIFY body here
        return body;
    }
}
```